# How to change my commandline locale after CentOS decided to change it?

Tags: linux, centos, command-line-interface, localization

So apparently, CentOS decided I was Dutch, and thus, should not have a English locale.

Apart from the fact that this greatly bothers me, I am having a pretty hard time actually changing it back. There does not seem to be a `setlocale` function, and `system-config-language` tells me I am using an English locale, even though my environment says otherwise.

Any help would be appreciated.

Output from `locale`:

```
LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Both my ~/.bashrc as ~/.bash_profile contain no locale settings. Additionally, `/etc/bashrc` does not contain any locale references either.

Comment: Make sure `LANGUAGE` is not set (or set to your desired value). It is not listed by `locale` but still overrides all other language settings in command line software like vim and dnf.

Answer (score 5):

I just stumbled on this exact same problem, and found out why this is happens in my case and thought i'd share. I recently got a new iMac at work that runs OS X Lion (previous workstation was OS X Snow Leopard)

OS X Lion by default sets the locale in env variable LANG in Terminal. This was set to nl_NL.UTF-8. Sshd on the CentOS system imports this environment variable in its shell when you ssh into your CentOS box.

I solved it by disabling 'Set locale environment variables on startup' in Terminal preferences (settings->advanced)

Don't know if you run OS X on your desktop, but bottom line is: sshd on CentOS imports the locale settings from the ssh client workstation.

HTH

Answer (score 5):

If you use SSH, there is another way to achieve the same result, which works in iTerm as well. You must modify the SSH configuration:

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh_config
```

Find and comment out the line containing

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Answer (score 3):

If `system-config-language` doesn't help you, try this.

1. Go to the CentOS system configuration directory

   ```
   $ cd /etc/sysconfig
   ```
2. Make backup copy of your language setting file

   ```
   $ cp i18n i18n.backup
   ```
3. Edit language setting file to allow English as default. You can edit the file by using `nano` or `vim` text editors available on all CentOS systems from SSH. I prefer `vim`, but `nano` is more easier:

   ```
   $ nano i18n
   ```
4. Edit the file to include these lines as the first three lines of the file:

   ```
   $ LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
   $ SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
   $ SUPPORTED="en_US.UTF-8:en_US:en"
   ```
5. Save the file and restart system. If you can not restart the system you need to have permission to restart `init.d`

That should enable the new language setting. If you can not perform these through SSH because the access is too restricted, you will likely need to notify the ISP or whoever has physical access to the server.

Regards and best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

To check what locale are available on your system you can use “localectl” command with “list-locales” option

```
localectl list-locales |grep en_
```

To verify the current locale configuration. So you can change this file and choose a language from previews step:
#vi /etc/locale.conf

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

The language can also be changed by using “localectl”:  #localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Also add this to /etc/environment

#vi  /etc/environment

```
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

After that, just logout and login for the new configuration take effect

Answer (score 0):

At least Fedora 16 defines language in GRUB command line. See `/boot/grub/grub.conf` and `/etc/grub.conf`.

Then there's `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` file which contains language settings.